# Is it possible to drop tablespace CASCADE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql-5.6, cascade, drop-table

I am newbie with MySQL. I have created a tablespace with a datafile, and I have tried to drop this tablespace without drop any object in that tablespace by using that SQL query:

```
DROP TABESPACE TBS_TEST;
```

> ERROR 1529 (HY000): Failed to drop TABLESPACE

```
DROP TABESPACE TBS_TEST CASCADE ; ---also got ERROR
```

So, is it possible to `drop tablespace CASCADE` in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation it is not possible:

```
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-tablespace.html

Important
The tablespace to be dropped must not contain any data files; in other   
words, before you can drop a tablespace, you must first drop each of its 
data files using ALTER TABLESPACE ... DROP DATAFILE (see Section 13.1.8, 
“ALTER TABLESPACE Syntax”).
```

You can however locate the files that has to be dropped first, via INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES:

```
select ... 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES 
where TABLESPACE_NAME = ?
```

I'm not able to test this since I don't use any of the engines that support tablespaces.